# Authenticate to Untappd API with Oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I have a Rails app, I'm using "omniauth-untappd" gem to authenticate. It was working ok, but suddenly it stopped to work. 
When user tries to authenticate - the Rails app generate the correct URL described in https://untappd.com/api/docs#authentication - the API returns an error of invalid credentials. 
I doubled check the config file with the client id and it is ok. The problem happens to if I call the url direct from the browser (https://untappd.com/oauth/authenticate/?client_id=CLIENTID&response_type=code&redirect_url=REDIRECT_URL) so I don't think it is a problem with the gem.
Other strategies - facebook, twitter and untappd - works well in the same app.
May it be a problem in Untappd API? Something with Rails version?

The console log:

INFO -- : Started GET "/auth/untappd" for 191.17.67.26 at 2015-02-07 15:49:50 +0000

INFO -- : Started GET "/auth/untappd/callback?code=4FC137EB7AE5AAFB504F76C50C84B9C258FF79CC" for 191.17.67.26 at 2015-02-07 15:49:51 +0000

INFO -- : Started GET "/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials&strategy=untappd" for 191.17.67.26 at 2015-02-07 15:49:52 +0000

Comment: well, have you checked with a fresh pair of credentials?

Comment: Not yet @phoet; to request new credentials, it takes some days. You have to ask for another API license but it is not automatic, the Untappd support team first check what for you are requesting it :-/